# Probability of missing an event after repeated sampling (without order)

Tags: probability, combinations

Here is a real problem I have that I hope you could help me solve.. I'm no expert in probabilities but I've tried to simplify it as follow:

**Problem 1:**

There is a box which contains a number (T) of unique balls.

[A] is the event of pulling (C) balls from the box together in no specific order, and then returning them to the box.

We repeat the event [A] (N) times.

What is the probabilty of a ball not being pulled at all, that is we miss a ball?

(T is always unknown so the solution should be independent from it)

**Problem 2:**

Suppose that

C=25

N=100

and that we found only 52 balls.

What are the chances that we missed a ball?

Comment: My final goal of this problem is to know how many times the event [A] should be repeated, so that it would be almost impossible to miss a ball.

Comment: "Pulling the balls" is an experiment. "A specific ball is not drawn at all" is an event.

Comment: I doubt that the probability is independent of the number of balls ($T$). You need a formula of the probability depending on $T$. Hint : In each draw, the probability to miss a specific ball is $\frac{T-C}{T}$. Now guess what the probability is to miss it $N$ times in a row!